# (PHP/SQL) Won't pull from database based on query param

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm trying to build a php page to edit records.  Right now I'm trying to get it to take the ID in the url and return data based on that.  I can echo out the id from the url, that's fine, but the sql query isn't doing anything.  I threw the 2 echo's at the bottom to try to get them to display values.  The ID displays fine, coming from the URL, but it should display the name corrosponding with that gigid and isn't.

Any ideas?

```
<?php

 // query db

 $gigid = $_GET['gigid'];
 $result = ORM::for_table('gigs')->where('gigid', $gigid)
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 // check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse
 if($row)
 {
 // get data from db
        $gig_name = $row['gig_name'];
        $gig_type = $row['gig_type'];
        $gig_date = $row['gig_date'];
        $gig_customer = $row['gig_customer'];
        $gig_venue = $row['venue_name'];
        $gig_fee = $row['gig_fee'];
        $gig_status = $row['gig_status'];   
 }
mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
 <?php echo $gigid; ?>
 <?php echo $gig_name; ?>
```

Comment: Without knowing what kind of ORM approach you are using, people will have a hard time knowing what is wrong since we can't even see the actual SQL being generated. Also, you should try to check if any error is happening (one else in that if($row)) so you know if an error happened during the fetch. Either way, Xiaoyu approach would solve all of that (or, at least, make it easier to understand what is going on)

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs with `mysql_error()`, use its `mysqli_` equivalent, they do not mix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use mysqli_query for any database manipulation.

```
. . .
$con = mysqli_connect("i.p.addr","username","password","database");
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM gigs WHERE gigid=$gigid") or die(mysqli_error($con)); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
mysqli_close($con);
```

UPDATE:: changed to mysqli_error()

Comment: THANK YOU!!  That combined with moving it to the top of the file worked like a charm!